# Problems reinstalling Windoxs XP instead Ubuntu

Tags: uninstall

I've installed Ubuntu in my netbook using all hard disk. It runs, but I don't like it and I'm trying to reinstall Windows XP.

I use an external CD-ROM and the disk of installing Windows XP. That starts running, but it is interrupted because "it doesn't find any disk installed in my system". It doesn't recognize my hard disk! Someone knows what could I do?

Answer (score 3):

What OS did your netbook had originally?

XP needs some drivers to recognize some more modern hard drives, depending on what mode they're operating on.

My advice would be re-install whatever came with your netbook.

BTW, some more info on the netbook itself might produce better/more useful answers than this one (I hope i don't get downvoted...)

Comment: +1 This is the answer. Additionally I would say that not by operating a software you can harm a hardware. If the hard disk drive is having a failure itself you can't blame the OS. The same could happen with the original OS or any MS Based OS. I suggest you to first check out your hard disk drive (preferably in a different computer) and make sure it is working properly, after which you should check your connections/cables. And I am also for providing enough information about your question in order to receive a better support. Good luck!

Comment: +1 on using the same OS that was installed originally.  If I remember right, XP needed at least the a small partition in the first part of the drive formatted in NTFS to find the hard disk.  XP can then use the entire disk.  If you are going to wipe the hard drive anyway, I would suggest formatting the entire disk to NTFS by booting into the LiveCD and then using Gparted

Comment: Probably this is the question. My netbook had Windows XP. Installing ubuntu It is deleted the partition to recognize hard disk how you say. I'll look for help about getting LiveCD and using Gparted. Thank you very mutch.